# How to combine css file and xml file with a GTK3 project

Tags: css, xml, compilation, runtime, gtk3

I am using external css to theme my GTK3 application (on windows 7, 64bits)
also I am using xml file that describes all the widgets in the application

both of these two files (.css & .xml) are used during **runtime** of my application (.exe)

my question: how to compile my application so that it will no longer depend on the css and xml files ?

Answer (score 0):

Put the files inside a [`GResource`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gio-GResource.html) and compile them directly into your program.

The documentation explains it well enough, but basically you generate a `resource.c` and `resource.h` file during your build process, that encode the external files. Then you compile those files into your program, and they will be available through a URI such as `resource:///com/example/yourprogram/yourwidgets.xml`.